# Excel VBA If not equal not working

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have this problem where my code doesn't check if cell has the value I need. I used box to check value it look good from box, but if doesn't take value. Any ideas whats wrong? I tried add value manually to cells, but if does't working.

```
If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value <> "CH" Or ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value <> "SSC" Then 
   If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen - 1).value <> "CH" Or ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen - 1).value <> "SSC" Or ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen - 1).value <> "" Then  
       MsgBox ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen - 1).value
```

Comment: What happens when you change `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value` to `Ucase(Trim(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value))`. Similarly for other?

Comment: Also it would be a good idea to work with objects rather than `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` The active sheet may not be the one you think is active :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout just tried it, didn't work, He didn't check value, just went next instead of else. 
About 'Workbook.Activesheet'. Its automatic macro that works with generated sheets, that's not problem because i'm testing on one sheet.

Comment: Wat is the value of "Cells(virsus, desinen).value"

Comment: Normally its number or 'SSC' or 'CH' and sometimes it could be empty. But he don't check that at all.

Comment: `If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value <> "CH" Or ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value <> "SSC" Then` - this line always return `True`.  You check if this value is different than `CH` or different than `SSC`. Value cannot be equal to `CH` and `SSC` at the same time, so one of those expression always returns `True` and since they are connected with `OR` keyword, whole expression also always returns `True`. The same case with the second `If` statement.

Comment: @mielk: That is a valid answer. Maybe you want to post an answer with a short example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change expression you have in your `If` statements.

Currently, both of them returns always `True` and it is probably not what is expected.

Let's consider this line:

```
If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value <> "CH" Or _
                 ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value <> "SSC" Then
```

You check if this value is different than `CH` or different than `SSC`. Value cannot be equal to `CH` and `SSC` at the same time, so one of those expression always returns `True` and since they are connected with `Or` keyword, whole expression also always returns `True`.

I am not sure what you wanted to check in this `If` statement but I suppose it was expected to return `True` if the value is neither `CH` nor `SSC`. In this case you just need to replace operator `Or` with `And`:

```
If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value <> "CH" And _
                 ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(virsus, desinen).value <> "SSC" Then
```